# Make a hotspot cell F4-enabled while insert. Possible?

Tags: abap, alv

My requirement is as follows:

I show records in an alv grid (CL_GUI_ALV_GRID), where the user can add new ones.

- I have a keyfield, MATNR, which is **disabled** on existing records. This one does 
  not really need to have a working F4 SH icon. **It must have a hotspot**.
- When the user decides to add a new record, I want to allow F4,make the field a 
  hotspot and enable it.

However, it turns out, that neither combining cellstyles 1-4 works (appearently there is no combining of their raws resulting in a multiple style) , nor does fieldcat-f4available = abap_true work together with fieldcat-hotspot = abap_true.

I must admit, that I do not come often over this kind of requirements... therefore I am asking in here, if anybody knows a way (best practice preferred).

Until now I set the cellstyles depending on row-contents, and the fieldcat is set up more or less statically.

So in the fieldcat, F4 is set up, and in the celltab style MC_HOTSPOT is set up.
However, this also forbids to entering values manually. Only the F4 value remapping works.

Comment: Let me just confirm that I never saw fields with these 2 combinations in 15 years of CL_GUI_ALV_GRID.

Comment: Why else do 4 style options exist at all?

Comment: So let me articulate the problem: you cannot make field a hotspot and F4-enabled simultaneously?

Comment: It works, if combining cellstyles and fieldcat. But then two other things stop working:

1) Entering text into the cell.

2) Disabling the cell(because the celltab-style property is already occupied, by either F4 style or hotspot style, depends on what one did not set in thr fieldcat).

Answer (score 1):

I have just had this problem and thought I'd share my solution.
Apparently the way to combine styles is with bitwise operations:

```
ls_style-style = cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_style_hotspot BIT-OR 
                 cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_style_f4 BIT-OR
                 cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_style_enabled.
```

Should create an editable field with hotspot and F4.
You should also mark edit and hotspot in the field catalog.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have: editable field with f4 and hotspot. My solutions:
I set in ls_fcat :

`hotspot = abap_true, and f4avaliable = abap_true`

In style of field, I set:

`style = cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_style_f4 BIT-OR cl_gui_alv_grid=>mc_style_enabled`